# Installshield and Windows 8... can't find installed program

Tags: c#, windows-8, installshield, installshield-le

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and created an InstallShield project using the free Limited Edition. I built a SingleImage and ended up with a Setup.Exe... when I run this and I leave "Launch the program" checked it launches fine.

But when I try to search for it using the search tool on the right... or browse all the apps in the Windows 8 start screen... I don't find it.

When I run Setup.Exe again... it wants to Modify/Repair/Remove it... so it's there.

It's also in C:\Windows\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MyProgram

Is there something I need to do to get Windows 8 to be aware of it?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming question.  Perhaps here:  http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get "Shortcuts" of any kind desktop, start menu, etc... you need to complete the section "Application Shortcuts".

In this section you can create a "New..." shortcut and then name it the name of your application... then you can check "Create in start menu", "Create on desktop", etc...